# CSS attribute not value selector issue

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is set to `display: 'none'` by the framework our company is using.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none">...</div>
```

However when it is shown, it is set to `display: block`, but I need it to be `display: inline-block`. So I tried to style the div like this:

```
#mydiv:not([display='none']) {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

But it is not working like I was expecting. I want to achieve this with CSS only. Does somebody know how and if this is possible?

Comment: its enough `#mydiv{ display: inline-block!important; }`

Comment: You have [invalid selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)

Comment: [display='none'] - This is not an attribute of the element itself.  Style would be the attribute.  However, # (ID's) should be used to target a specific/unique element, there should not be multiples.  So targeting the ID itself should be enough.

Comment: Ok I got it now, thank you! I just realised that my question contained I mistake of myself, I wanted to select #mydiv only if it has its display style NOT set to 'none'.

Comment: @Chris nope it isn't working.. When the `div` gets the attribute `style="display: block"` assigned, the `display` value is still `block`!

Comment: @Chris Nevermind, looks like Chrome is not differentiating between `block` and `display-block` in the computed styles section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQZada
Here the attribute to check is `style`, (not `display`)

```
#mydiv[style="display: none"] {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Anyway this is a weak approach, since a change in the markup (e.g. a minification of inline stlye, or an editor change) can affect the style (and viceversa).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just realised that my question contained a few mistakes.. haha

Comment: Well, it isn't really working.. But your answer is correct in general. I now got it like this `#module_area[style*="display: block"]) {
 display: inline-block !important;
}`, however when the `display: block` style is set, it does not change to `display: inline-block !important`. What am i doing wrong here? Or is it just because the `!important` is somehow blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

Just targeting the element by it's id should be enough to override its inline style:

```css
#mydiv {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none">Test Div</div>
```

**But**

For the sake of the question, regarding to selection an element by its inline style value, you could target the `[style]` attibute and check for the desired text value

*(Trouble is that you'd need to match the exact written form of the style property)*

```css
#mydiv[style*="display: none"] {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none">Test Div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Today I realised that my question contained mistakes. I want to select #mydiv only if it's display style is NOT set to none. I got it now, thanks! :)